Self differencing function for 2D numpy array (correlation?)
I have a 2D array mat of shape ~ (3000, 5). Now I want to subtract every column from the others and ignore the self subtraction. This is what I have right now and what works. I just want a more efficient way of doing this, like a self correlation or something. Is there a numpy or scipy function that allows me to do this with less steps instead of the usual for loop?
agreement = np.full((mat.shape[1], mat.shape[1]), [np.nan]*mat.shape[0])
for i in range(agreement.shape[0] - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, agreement.shape[1]):
        A = mat[:, i]
        B = mat[:, j]
        diff = A - B
        agreement[i][j] = diff

The result is a 2d array agreement that looks something like this:
array([[nan [......] [......] [......] [......]]
       [nan nan [......] [......] [......]]
       [nan nan nan [......] [......]]
       [nan nan nan nan [......]]
       [nan nan nan nan nan]])

Each of the [......] represents the diff of those 2 columns and is thus of shape (3000,1) and is not an accurate representation, just to give an example. Each of the nan represents the array [np.nan]*mat.shape[0]

It may be faster to take the full difference, and set the lower triangle of nan after.

It seems like the result you are asking for would require NumPy to support jagged arrays, i.e. an array of arrays where each inner array has different length, which NumPy doesn't support. Am I understanding right?

Oh yes, thanks for catching that, yes I would need to make the array to have a homogeneous shape.

np.corrcoef(mat, rowvar=False) will give you real correlation matrix for your 5 columns
To make array of diffs you describe, use:
agreement = (
    np.stack([mat] * mat.shape[1], axis=1).T - 
    np.stack([mat.T] * mat.shape[1], axis=0)
)

in this array
agreement[a, b] = mat[:, a] - mat[:, b]
but there will be no nan in low triangle of matrix

yes, the np.corrcoef() and np.coef() functions seem incorrect for my usage. I will try this method, thanks you :) Is this efficient when running for about 250 such matrices?

The only limit is your memory, I think: you need place to contain N ** 2 columns (where N is your initial number of columns), and twice more during processing. But time complexity is ridiculously low for this algorithm and every operation is vectorized.

Space is not an issue, only time. Thanks for the thorough answer and followup.
